# how to display the ID of a visible DIV on screen jquery. (when the Div visible on the browser screen appropriate ID should alert))

Tags: jquery

getdivs.php

```
<div class="same" id="childcontainer1">  
    content here content here content here  
</div> 
<div class="same" id="childcontainer2"> 
    content here content here content here  
</div>
```

index.php

```
<html>
<head> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquerys\jquery.js"></script> 
    <style>
        #parentcontainer div {  
            height: 500px;  
            width: 600px;                  
            clear: both;                  
            border: 1px solid red;   
            padding: 10px;  
            margin: 50px 0px;  
        } 
    </style> 
    <script>  
        function showHint() { 
            $('div').load('getdivs.php');  
            $('body').on('click', '.same1 , .same ', function() {
                alert($(this).attr('id'));     
            }); 
        }  
    </script>
</head> 
<body onload="showHint()"> 
    <p>
        Suggestions: 
        <div class="same2" id="parentcontainer"></div>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I can get it on click but I want it when I am scrolling the browser. Appropriate ID should be displayed to the divs. I have been searching this from past 24 hours. Please help thank you.

Comment: Please take the time to format your code so it is readable. You will get far more help if you make the effort to make your question easy to follow.

Comment: thank you for editing i am new to this . i can get the ' ID ' of the 'DIV' on click from above code but i need the 'ID' of visible ' DIV ' automatically when i am scrolling down the page .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, you're looking to run the same login upon browser scroll...

Check out `.scroll()` from jQuery's documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/).

Comment: i am looking to get the ID on DIV  viewport.  i can get the ' ID ' of the 'DIV' on click from above code but i need the 'ID' of visible ' DIV ' automatically when i am scrolling down the page

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('div').each(function(){
    if($(this).offset().top + $(this).height() > cutoff){
        alert("Div id : "+$(this).attr("id"));
        return false; // stops the iteration after the first one on screen
    }
});
```

It will alert the current Div ID that appears on the screen